# How to index email address and then find

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to create mapping for email address but without no success.

What I want to do is to insert into ElasticSearch email addresses and then make a search on it.
For eample.
I have inserted this emails:

```
abc1@abc.net
Abc1@abc.NET
abc2@abc.net
abC2@ABC.net
abc3@abc.net
abc4@abc.net
```

and when I make a search with:

```
http://localhost:9200/emails/_search?q=email:abc1@abc.net
```

I want to get only two document with this specific emails:

```
abc1@abc.net
Abc1@abc.NET
```

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom normalizer with a lowercase filter, lowercase filter will ensure that all the letters are changed to lowercase before indexing the document and searching.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "email": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "email": "Abc1@abc.NET"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66170150",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.4700036,
        "_source": {
          "email": "abc1@abc.net"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66170150",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.4700036,
        "_source": {
          "email": "Abc1@abc.NET"
        }
      }
    ]
```

You can also use [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) if you have to use the [uax_url_email tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html)

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "uax_url_email"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "email": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Query in this case will be

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "email.raw": "Abc1@abc.NET"
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

You can also use the lowercase filter, to achieve your use case

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter":"lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "uax_url_email"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "email": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can we do this using "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",